# External VGA monitor isn't detected. How do I fix this

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have an ASUSPro Laptop Model P2420L (CPU: i5 5500U, RAM: 8GB, GPU: Intel HD 5500 Graphics), and my screen stopped working yesterday, and when I plugged an Acer external monitor using a VGA cable, the GUI system isn't working properly. When I boot it, it works fine, and when I'm presented with the login page, I can enter my password and connect normally, but afterwards, it gets stuck on a blank screen I can only use command line to work on it.

When I type `xrandr` on the command prompt I get the following:

> Can't open display (You can zoom in the image)

And all displays are OFF.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cIli.jpg

Comment: `xrandr` only works with Xorg sessions, and since 21.04, unless you have an Nvidia graphics card (do you?), all sessions are Wayland, not Xorg, by default.

Comment: I'm booting linux normally and pressing ALT+CTRL+F6 to use command line session, but the issue is that my external VGA monitor is not working. I have an Intel HD 5500 GPU, nothing fancy.

Comment: any useful tips in [this reference](https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1015072/)?

Comment: This https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1015072/ is all for windows, I'm using Ubuntu Linux 20.04.

Comment: Could you press the switch monitor layout keys, i.e. [Fn] and [F8] when the session starts? Maybe the session has disabled the external monitor?

Comment: Nothing happens, it stays in the command line.